# How to getName on java.io.file.listFiles?

Tags: java, javafx

Here is my code, a basic treeview for directory listing in the javafx listview api, modified a bit for my needs.

```
    def home_dir = System.getProperty("user.home");
    def dir = new File("{home_dir}/Android_Surgeon/Projects");

var projectTree = TreeView {

        root: TreeItem {
        data: dir
        expanded:false
        isLeaf: isLeaf
        createChildren: createChildren;
    }
    showRoot: false
```

}

```
function createChildren(item:TreeItemBase):TreeItemBase[] {
var file = item.data as File;
if (file.isDirectory()) {
    return for (f in file.listFiles()) {
        TreeItem {
            data: f
            createChildren: createChildren;
            isLeaf: isLeaf;
        }
    }

}
return [];
```

}

```
function isLeaf(item:TreeItemBase):Boolean {
def file = item.data as File;
return file.isFile();
```

}

I am fairly new to programming, I can't figure out how to get the names of the java.io.file array for loop in the createchildren function. when this code is ran it lists the absolute path of every item on the treeview, makes it ugly and hard to read. An alternative I would use as well is how to get the name  of my def dir = new File("{home_dir}/Android_Surgeon/Projects"), then go ahead and let the subfolders and files have the absolute path. The first option is preferred. Been a week of trying on my own, tired and need help!!! Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

That looks like Javascript, not Java. But if that `File` class is Java's, then you simply call `f.getName()`. Looking at your code, I'm guessing you'd want to set the `data` of the `TreeItem` to the filename.

So:

```
TreeItem {
    data: f.getName();
    createChildren: createChildren;
    isLeaf: isLeaf;
}
```

Either that, or set `data` to some wrapper for the `File` object which implements `toString` to return only the name.

Comment: Here is what I get when I run f.getName()                    Exception in binding:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.io.File
        at openproject.Main.isLeaf(Main.fx:63)